# Auto-click using vb.net code a button that lies on a cell in a macro-enabled excel

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

I have a macro-enabled excel created by other company, it's protected and its password cannot be shared to me hence I cannot view the code. The objective is to auto-populate it with data before submitting it back to them. In certain cells, there are buttons which purpose is to add new row when clicked. I want to trigger that button then insert data using vb.net code. Right-click in the entire row > insert rows is disabled as well.

I can just select the cells where the buttons are but cannot trigger the buttons.

Comment: It's easy to break password protected excel files. What you could do is to create a copy of the file, break the passwords and then figure out what the sub is called to add lines, then you create an add-in file on your computer that triggers this sub. I'm not sure this will work but it would be worth a try. When all that is done you should be able to use the real password protected file with your add-in.